# How to wrap or call a C function with void as return in Emscripten?

Tags: emscripten

In the Emscripten wiki ([Interacting with code](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Interacting-with-code)), there are only two types listed as possible return types to be passed to `ccall` or `cwrap` ("number" and "string"). How can I wrap / call a function which doesn't return anything (void return type)?

Comment: `undefined` is the conceptual equivalent.

Comment: After successfully using cwrap with `null` as return type, I tried the same with `undefined` and it seems to work as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"null" works as a return type for void functions instead of a string.

For example:

```
    my_fun = Module.cwrap('my_fun', null, ['number', 'number']);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Examples on the site](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/350550a5ccfacd19f512bca2ded186e143ea9579/tests/Module-exports) also use `number`, as it will just be ignored. This is what the example in the wiki uses.

I use this in all of my emscripted code, and it works great. In general, looking in the examples folder of the `emscripten` repo is your best bet for syntax. Also, this is the documented use, so it may be safer to hedge against future changes.

---

For example, a C function

```
void test(char* buffer, int buffersize) {
  // ...
}
```

could be wrapped as

```
var test = Module.cwrap('test', 'number', ['number', 'number']);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the examples directory! I didn't know it existed before.

Comment: Concerning all of those 'number' elements: I think for the return type I'll stick with null or undefined, putting in 'number' in there simpy makes no sense. I'm curious about that first parameter though: Why manually allocate the space with Module._malloc and then pass a pointer to the wrapper function instead of simply using 'string' as parameter type?

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer, but I can definitely hazard a guess:

It may have been written before 'string' was a thing, but more likely this example tests it better and showcases more general passing techniques, as the tests are often referenced (in the wiki) as examples.